# SQL Server 2016 - Split quantities over maximum value in row to new row(s)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of orders which contains a total quantity on the order.  If the total quantity is over a maximum (determined by the product) then I need to split each order into a new row, and the process may need to loop multiple times per original order line depending on the quantity.  I was able to do this in Excel quite easily using an indexed pivot table and relative vlookups, but I am attempting to rebuild the same functionality properly in SQL and I am frankly over my head.

Sample data looks like:

```
    SalesOrder  SKU  QtyOpen PerOrderMax
 1  SO1         L06  1144    192
 2  SO3         S01  768     256
 3  SO4         S04  832     256
```

Quantities less than the order maximum would be left as is on the last line for the order.  From the above sample data the ideal result would be:

```
    SalesOrder  SKU  QtyOpen PerOrderMax  NewOrderQty
 1  SO1         L06  1144    192          192
 2  SO1         L06  952     192          192
 3  SO1         L06  760     192          192
 4  SO1         L06  568     192          192
 5  SO1         L06  376     192          192
 6  SO1         L06  184     192          184
 7  SO3         S01  768     256          256
 8  SO3         S01  512     256          256
 9  SO3         S01  256     256          256
10  SO4         S04  832     256          256
11  SO4         S04  576     256          256
12  SO4         S04  320     256          256
13  SO4         S04   64     256           64
```

So essentially I am looking to do a subtotal in reverse, but I have no idea how to break the quantities down into new lines based on a variable maximum.  I have a hunch that I can probably work CTE to loop through the list, but unfortunately I am learning as I go and I just don't understand it very well.

Comment: Another approach I have considered is handling 'full' orders and the last remaining quantity differently.  If I were to do what I know with CTE and loop for the number of full orders, setting the quantity on the orders to the maximum, then merge that table with another which just contains the modulo I might get what I am looking for.  I will try and make that approach work and post back if I have any success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select salesorder, sku, QtyOpen, PerOrderMax,
             (case when QtyOpen > PerOrderMax then PerOrderMax else QtyOpen end) as NewOrderQty
      from t
      union all
      select salesorder, sku, QtyOpen - PerOrderMax, PerOrderMax,
             (case when QtyOpen - PerOrderMax > PerOrderMax then PerOrderMax else QtyOpen - PerOrderMax end) as NewOrderQty
      from cte
      where QtyOpen - PerOrderMax > 0
    )
select *
from cte
order by salesorder, QtyOpen desc;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, tested and working in my environment with only a few modifications due to my source being a join of 3 tables and not a single true table.  I was able to set it up as a stored procedure so I can call it on demand for new batches of orders, thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @JeffMalone . . . If the sizes are too large, you may need the `MAXRECURSION` option.

Answer (score 0):

Without going recursive you can do this with a `union all` where the top query returns 1 row for each `qtyopen/perordermax` and the bottom query returns 1 row with the remainder (if there is one) using modulo `%`

```
select 
    t.SalesOrder
  , t.sku
  , QtyOpen = QtyOpen - (rn*PerOrderMax)
  , t.PerOrderMax
  , NewOrderQty = perordermax 
from t
  cross apply (
      select top (t.qtyopen/t.perordermax) 
        rn = row_number() over (order by (select 1))-1
      from master..spt_values
      ) x
union all 
select 
    t.SalesOrder
  , t.sku
  , QtyOpen = qtyopen%perordermax
  , t.PerOrderMax
  , NewOrderQty = qtyopen%perordermax
from t
where qtyopen%perordermax != 0
order by SalesOrder, NewOrderQty desc
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/ZYCXU77250

returns:

```
+------------+-----+---------+-------------+-------------+
| SalesOrder | sku | QtyOpen | PerOrderMax | NewOrderQty |
+------------+-----+---------+-------------+-------------+
| so1        | L06 |    1144 |         192 |         192 |
| so1        | L06 |     952 |         192 |         192 |
| so1        | L06 |     760 |         192 |         192 |
| so1        | L06 |     568 |         192 |         192 |
| so1        | L06 |     376 |         192 |         192 |
| so1        | L06 |     184 |         192 |         184 |
| so3        | S01 |     768 |         256 |         256 |
| so3        | S01 |     512 |         256 |         256 |
| so3        | S01 |     256 |         256 |         256 |
| so4        | S04 |     832 |         256 |         256 |
| so4        | S04 |     576 |         256 |         256 |
| so4        | S04 |     320 |         256 |         256 |
| so4        | S04 |      64 |         256 |          64 |
+------------+-----+---------+-------------+-------------+
```

Comment: This is exactly where my brain was headed, and I may pursue it further just to add it to my toolkit since it seems to fit better with where my skills are at now.  The recursive CTE solution is what I ended up going with, but thank you very much for your input.

Comment: @JeffMalone That's cool. If performance is any consideration, you should evaluate the performance between the two methods in your environment.  http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=1d9ddf16dcf3c40923ae384bcb762ef4